# Filelight /home in /usr/share

Tags: files, fedora, memory, disk-cleanup

I needed to remove some files in / and I noticed I have a folder /home/myusername in /usr/share whereas no such folder appear when I list the directoty, symbolik link or else in /usr/share.

What could be the cause ?

[image]

Here is my config :

```
 :-----------/shhOHbmp---:\      OS: Fedora release 32 (Thirty Two) x86_64 
   /-----------omMMMNNNMMD  ---:     Host: HP EliteBook 840 G5 
  :-----------sMMMMNMNMP.    ---:    Kernel: 5.8.4-200.fc32.x86_64 
 :-----------:MMMdP-------    ---\   Uptime: 3 hours, 51 mins 
,------------:MMMd--------    ---:   Packages: 7623 (rpm) 
:------------:MMMd-------    .---:   Shell: zsh 5.8 
:----    oNMMMMMMMMMNho     .----:   Resolution: 1920x1080 
:--     .+shhhMMMmhhy++   .------/   DE: Plasma 
:-    -------:MMMd--------------:    WM: KWin 
:-   --------/MMMd-------------;     Theme: Breeze Dark [Plasma], Adwaita [GTK2] 
:-    ------/hMMMy------------:      Icons: breeze-dark [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 
:-- :dMNdhhdNMMNo------------;       Terminal: konsole 
:---:sdNMMMMNds:------------:        Terminal Font: Monospace 11 
:------:://:-------------::          CPU: Intel i7-8550U (8) @ 4.000GHz 
:---------------------://            GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
                                     Memory: 4511MiB / 7798MiB
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's in /usr/share?  To me it looks like it's in just plain ole /home.

Firelight is telling you there are 91,000 files taking 2.1G in /home/fernand.

If you use "du -hs /home/fernand", what does it tell you?

In unix, when a file path begins with "/", it implies the beginning is in the root directory and goes from there.  Relative paths begin with "./" and in this case, filelite shows the path beginning with /.

Comment: To be strict: [a relative path does not begin with `/`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_324), it may *or may not* begin with `./`. These are also relative: `foo`, `foo/bar`, `../`, `.`.

Comment: True.  I was trying to keep it simple just to show his paths were beginning with / vs a relative one. :-)